# How do I buy special vehicles?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In Grand Theft Auto V, how do you buy special cars? I just went into my garage and it said press right on the d-pad and it showed one special car. I was wondering how to buy more.

Comment: I'm guessing you have to buy DLC.

Comment: Are these the cars you can buy on the web from your mobile phone in-game? They are mostly $1,000,000 each.